# Android Force quit CountDownTimer/Toast

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, popup, toast

So I have this "hack" to have a toast duration a little bit longer:

```
// Toast...
zanimivosti = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
zanimivosti.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
zanimivosti.setView(layout);

new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        zanimivosti.show();
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        zanimivosti.show();
    }

}.start();
```

PROBLEM: When a user go to another intent, it can happen that the toast reaper again in new intent.
In my case CountDownTimer.cancel(); won't work

ALTERNATIVE:
In my toast I am displaying news every time the user lunch the app. I would also take in consideration a better solution whit a toast that when a user click on it disappear or when new intent is called also disappear.
Should I use a pop up dialog? Can I make it disappear when user clicks on it?

Comment: why not using a usual Dialog?  You can cancel it with button click or by click besides and the message stays on screen.

Comment: Because if there is a dialog you have first to dismiss it before going to another activity for example..
And the dialog comes in front placing itself in centre of attention..

Comment: not exactly...You can put it in the DialogInterface.OnClickListener to start the new activity and close the dialog with dialog.cancel();

Comment: Still is not what I am looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I did it like this:

```
Toast zanimivosti;
int cas = 4000;
int perioda = 1000;
boolean boolean_toast = true;
CountDownTimer timer;

timer = new CountDownTimer(time, perioda) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        zanimivosti.show();
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        if (boolean_toast == true) {
            zanimivosti.show();
        } else {
        }
    }
}.start();
```

And stoping the timer with stopping/cancelling all the possible things:

```
        boolean_toast = false;
        time = 0;
        perioda = 0;
        timer.cancel();
        zanimivosti.cancel();
```